# Default value for int in OrmLite Android

Tags: android, database, ormlite

I'm wondering how I can set the `defualt value` for an `int` in a `DatabaseField` in OrmLite for Android.

I have tried:

```
@DatabaseField(defaultValue = 0) 
int intValue;
```

But all I get is a compilation error. 
Or can you even do this with int's?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm wondering how I can set the defualt value for an int in a DatabaseField in OrmLite for Android.

The `defaultValue` field is a `String` so you can do:

```
@DatabaseField(defaultValue = "0") 
int intValue;
```

By setting it on the field with `intValue = 10`, that will work but it doesn't set the default-value on the database which typically is what you want.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with negative value. (I am using long, but it should be the same). It always assign 0.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply assign a value to your intValue in the class.

```
@DatabaseField() 
int intValue=10;
```

This makes intValue 10 by default, until you set it to something else.

Comment: Btw this only works if you don't need to call an SQLite function :)

Answer (score 1):

Hello the doc specifies it does not apply with primitive field, you must use  Integer class instead. It was the solution for me.

```
@DatabaseField(defaultValue = "0")
Integer intValue;
```